Problem with batch file that is analysing data from a text file
I have some code that is reading a text file line by line and doing some analysis on it.
The loop checks if each line starts with a number and then if it starts with a number it needs to validate information at a certain position on that line.
This part if working.
However I also need to check that the last line has an entry "END" - if it has an END that is fine but if not it should provide an error message.
Data is as follows :
VOL1FirstLine
HeaderLine1                 
HeaderLine2                                 00                            
Uline                                        
1212314214152156182651265172651782658172561651SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
1212314214152156182651265172651782658172561651SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
4125151514214152156182651265172651782658172561SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
1312442141431421415215618265126517265178265817SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
1312442141431421415215618265126517265178265817SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
4125151514214152156182651265172651782658172561SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
4125151514214152156182651265172651782658172561SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
4125151514214152156182651265172651782658172561SAMPLETEXTTOFailSNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
41251515142141521561826512651726517826581725616SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada     adafaafaf  
4125151514214152156182651265172651782658172561SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKNumbersadada  adafaafaf  
EOF121412415152                 
EOF214125151514             
UTL                                                   
END

So the line with SAMPLETEXTTOFail should fail and this is working correctly. But I cannot get my code to check the last line.
Version 1 of Code is as follows :
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

REM hard coded for now - this is the value i want to check against
set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
echo %NewName%
pause

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)
goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Rem get first three characters for testing End is present on last row
set "ThreeChar=%Line:~0,3%"
Echo %ThreeChar%

Rem get first character to check if a number as data rows to check start with a number
set "FirstChar=%Line:~0,1%"
Echo %FirstChar%

Rem check if first character is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
if defined var (echo %FirstChar% NOT numeric) else (echo %FirstChar% numeric)

rem if numeric read in
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
rem if numeric then read in variable
if not defined var set "SchemeTest=%Line:~46,18%"
REM Test against expected value
echo %SchemeTest%
REM this line below not yet tested
REM if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold unexpected data, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if not defined var if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold data for more than one client, please review.

PAUSE 


rem commented out as never seems to run
echo should be out of the loop here
rem last entry should be end
REM if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review. 

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

PAUSE

I think the problem is where I am putting these lines :
rem commented out as never seems to run
echo should be out of the loop here
rem last entry should be end
REM if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review.

If I put them after the ENDLOCAL goto :eof they don't run. If i put them before the ENDLOCAL goto :eof they run for every line.
I don't need to run this bit of code on every line i just need to run it on the last line that has been read in. I was thinking that if i did this after the loop has finished this would work as the variable %threechar% should still have the value of the final pass through the loop.
I know that EOF exits a subroutine and endlocal resets the variables. So this needs to happen after the loop and before end local. I have tried various combinations and placements of the code and EOF, ENDLOCAL but at the moment i can only get it to run every time or not at all.
My code has lots of echo's and pauses in so I can see what is happening line by line. There are also various rem statements to help me with debugging.
Any help would be appreciated.
Version 2 code with updates to pass variable after end local using (endlocal&set) this still did not work as no commands run after the final:
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

REM hard coded for now - this is the value i want to check against
set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
echo %NewName%
pause

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)
goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Rem get first three characters for testing End is present on last row
set "ThreeChar=%Line:~0,3%"
Echo %ThreeChar%

Rem get first character to check if a number as data rows to check start with a number
set "FirstChar=%Line:~0,1%"
Echo %FirstChar%

Rem check if first character is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
if defined var (echo %FirstChar% NOT numeric) else (echo %FirstChar% numeric)

rem if numeric read in
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
rem if numeric then read in variable
if not defined var set "SchemeTest=%Line:~46,18%"
REM Test against expected value
echo %SchemeTest%
REM this line below not yet tested
REM if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold unexpected data, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if not defined var if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold data for more than one client, please review.

PAUSE 



endlocal&set "threechar=%threechar%"
goto :eof


rem commented out as never seems to run
echo should be out of the loop here
rem last entry should be end
REM if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW

echo %threechar%
REM GH CODE if NOT "%ThreeChar%" == "END"  echo ERROR: This file appears to have no End row, please review. 
REM NEW CODE
If Not "%ThreeChar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line

PAUSE

Version 3 code updated so that the check runs immediately before the first goto end eof
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

REM hard coded for now - this is the value i want to check against
set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
echo %NewName%
pause

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)

ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE
ECHO %ThreeChar% FROM END ROW
If Not "%ThreeChar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line
goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Rem get first three characters for testing End is present on last row
set "ThreeChar=%Line:~0,3%"
Echo %ThreeChar%

Rem get first character to check if a number as data rows to check start with a number
set "FirstChar=%Line:~0,1%"
Echo %FirstChar%

Rem check if first character is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
if defined var (echo %FirstChar% NOT numeric) else (echo %FirstChar% numeric)

rem if numeric read in
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
rem if numeric then read in variable
if not defined var set "SchemeTest=%Line:~46,18%"
REM Test against expected value
echo %SchemeTest%
REM this line below not yet tested
REM if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold unexpected data, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if not defined var if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold data for more than one client, please review.

PAUSE 



endlocal
goto :eof

Version 4 of code a combination of v2 and v3 (includes compo suggestion and
magoo)
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

REM hard coded for now - this is the value i want to check against
set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
echo %NewName%
pause

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)

ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE
ECHO %ThreeChar% FROM END ROW
If Not "%ThreeChar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line

If Not "%myVar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line
Echo %myvar%

goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Rem get first three characters for testing End is present on last row
set "ThreeChar=%Line:~0,3%"
Echo %ThreeChar%

Rem get first character to check if a number as data rows to check start with a number
set "FirstChar=%Line:~0,1%"
Echo %FirstChar%

Rem check if first character is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
if defined var (echo %FirstChar% NOT numeric) else (echo %FirstChar% numeric)

rem if numeric read in
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
rem if numeric then read in variable
if not defined var set "SchemeTest=%Line:~46,18%"
REM Test against expected value
echo %SchemeTest%
REM this line below not yet tested
REM if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold unexpected data, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if not defined var if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold data for more than one client, please review.

PAUSE 


endlocal&set "threechar=%threechar%"
REM endlocal
goto :eof


Surely your last line is accessible as the final value of the variable you defined as myVar. So using the same variable expansion and replacement code you already have used If "%myVar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Last line is END.

Or I suppose, If Not "%myVar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line..

Thanks that line will run in the loop but it needs to be outside the loop (or only run on the last pass) as there are earlier lines where it is valid that the first three characters aren't "END" I just need to check that the last line has and "END". So i think the code will work just needs to be in the correct place?

yes, outside the loop. Move Compo's line just before your very first goto :eof - directly after the main loop. %MyVar% at this place will hold the last non-empty line of the text file.

Thanks @Stephan Ahh i see the last place before it comes our of the loop :) I have updated it there as follows but it does not seem to run this code ? Updated code in original post and starts with "**ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE"

@GravyTrain, why are you using %ThreeChar:*:=%, when both my comments specifically gave you options using %myVar:*:=%? There is no point in asking for help if you are going to ignore that help. Just change it to If Not "%myVar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line.

@Compo thanks I did try that but could not get it to run either. I have it here FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (
set "myVar=%%a"
call :processLine myVar
)
ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE
If Not "%myVar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line
Echo %myvar%
goto :eof`
I have updated code version 4 above which now has this entry in as well as other suggestions below. This section of code doesn't seem to run unless i put it in the loop section but then it runs every line. I put an echo there but the echo doesn't even run.

@Compo I think i am doing something fundamentally wrong but I can't see it so appreciate any help you can give. I was also using suggestions from Magoo below but not been able to get either to work.

@Compo I have done some more debugging and investigation today and I think the issue is with the goto :eof - as i understand it this is used to exit the for loop each time the code loops through. However i think on the final pass through the code it then exits the bat file?  So it doesn't run the remaining code? After the looping is finished I need it to continue running other non looping code.

@GravyTrain, you wanted "to check that the last line has an entry END". And you submitted code using FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ D:\sample.TXT"`) do (     set "myVar=%%a". You told us "The loop checks if each line" and "This part if working". If what you said was true, my comments were to inform you that the working loop you posted already does upon completion capture the last line of the findstr results. IMO, your entire question requires an overhaul, it has become too unfocused, (and TBH your entire script requires a complete rewrite too).

@Compo thanks again, I agree but it also represents my confusion. I am able to capture the last row of text but I need to be able to test that is has an entry "END". The number of rows in my file varies, an end is expected but I need to test that the value on the last row is "END" and if not provide an error message. I have the loop bit working but I have so far been unable to get the validation of the "END" part to work - I can do this in the loop but I need to understand how to do it only for the last row or to pass the final row out to do the test.

You are only defining myVar once, and never re-defining or modifying that variable. That means after your loop has completed, %myVar% will always hold the content of the last line, (in this case preceded by the line number followed by a colon). So that means my initial comments still remain accurate.

@compo thanks again for all your help. I know understand that I needed to call my bat file from another piece of code to do what I wanted (i didn't realize you could call another bat and was trying to write it all in one). I now have this working. Thanks for your patience and really appreciate your time. I have learned a lot from you and everyone else on this website and I really appreciate it.

The key assertion that you have made is the variable %threechar% should still have the value of the final pass through the loop.
Well, - it does -- when the endlocal or goto :eof is executed, but the endlocal reverts the environment to its state at setlocal.
The classic way to allow a variable to be maintained across the endlocal barrier is the apparently odd piece of code
endlocal&set "threechar=%threechar%"

The parser, which checks the validity of the logical code line translates this as
endlocal&set "threechar=<the current value of threechar>"

and then the two commands
endlocal
set "threechar=<the current value of threechar>"

are executed, where <the current value of threechar> is the value of threechar at the time that the line endlocal&set "threechar=%threechar%" was encountered.
Here's my test version.
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

REM hard coded for now - this is the value i want to check against
set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
echo %NewName%
pause

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ c:\106x\q78394131.txt"`) do (
    set "myVar=%%a"
    call :processLine myVar
)

**ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE
ECHO %ThreeChar% FROM END ROW
If Not "%ThreeChar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line**
echo i need to run some code here 
echo ++%threechar%++

goto :eof

:processLine
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=!%1!"
set "line=!line:*:=!"
echo(!line!

Rem get first three characters for testing End is present on last row
set "ThreeChar=%Line:~0,3%"
Echo %ThreeChar%

Rem get first character to check if a number as data rows to check start with a number
set "FirstChar=%Line:~0,1%"
Echo %FirstChar%

Rem check if first character is a number
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
if defined var (echo %FirstChar% NOT numeric) else (echo %FirstChar% numeric)

rem if numeric read in
SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%FirstChar%") do set var=%%i
rem if numeric then read in variable
if not defined var set "SchemeTest=%Line:~46,18%"
REM Test against expected value
echo %SchemeTest%
REM this line below not yet tested
REM if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold unexpected data, please review. & goto ErrorExit
REM REMOVE ERROR EXIT FOR NOW
if not defined var if NOT "%SchemeTest%" == "%NewName%"  echo ERROR: This file appears to hold data for more than one client, please review.

PAUSE 

endlocal&SET "threechar=%threechar%"
goto :eof

All I recall changing is that the data filename suits my system.
Here's the tail-end of the result.
Press any key to continue . . .
END
END
E
E NOT numeric
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
'**ECHO' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
END FROM END ROW
i need to run some code here
++END++

What I'd suggest is to cut-and-paste my code into a new file and execute
fc /w yourcodefile mycodefile

which would display the differences. The /w means "ignore whitespace"
Obviously, the '**ECHO' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. message is from the **ECHO THIS IS WHERE THE CODE CHECKS END LINE instruction.
Debugging tip: The ECHO is off. response is from the line echo %SchemeTest% where SchemeTest has not been set, hence the resultant command is echo, so cmd reports the echo status. You can get a more helpful response by using echo ++%SchemeTest%++ so that the argument to echo is never empty.

Thanks Magoo that makes sense - I still have issue though that after the endlocal and eof my code does not run? If i put it before it runs on every loop. If I put it after it doesn't run? It can't run in the loop as earlier lines would fail, so i need to test on the last line read only.  I have tried all the combinations I can think of i.e. after eof, but before end local.  I updated the original post with my latest code at the bottom,

I don't see endlocal&SET "threechar=%threechar%" in your code.

hi @Magoo it's in the 2nd set of code above in my original message - the text before it is "Latest code with updates to pass variable after end local :"

Rhetorical: Why did you remove it between the second-last and last code you posted (code block #3 and code block #4)? It needs to be retained there.

after trying your solution it still was not working as the code after 'endlocal&SET "threechar=%threechar%"' did not run? So in my code block 3 i tried another solution suggested in the comments above which was to do the check immediately before the first eof. I tried this but this did not work either. I have added a further code block 4 with your change also and updated version notes before each to try and make it clearer. Expect I am doing something very simple incorrectly but I can't see it. It doesn't even run my echo command so appear to be doing something fundamental wrong.

I have done some more debugging and investigation today and I think the issue is with the goto :eof - as i understand it this is used to exit the for loop each time the code loops through. However i think on the final pass through the code it then exits the bat file?  So it doesn't run the remaining code? After the looping is finished I need it to continue running other non looping code.

thanks again I tried your updated code and I still have the same issue i.e. after the second EOF no further code runs - I just added these two lines to your code  echo i need to run some code here echo ++%threechar%++ but they don't execute?
I need to run some code outside of the loop once i have the last line (which should be in threechar) to check if it has the value END or not. But these don't appear to execute?

No idea what you mean, unfortunately. There are only two goto :eof in the code I last posted. If you want to execute your two echo lines, then they must be placed between If Not "%ThreeChar:*:=%" == "END" Echo Error, invalid last line** & goto :eof

thanks again. Sorry if this has become confusing. When i put the code where you suggested it runs for every loop? I just want my code to run when it has the last line (or to be able to test the last line only). So I want to check the last line has an "END" or not. I don't understand how i can do this within the loop as earlier lines would fail the test and the last line may not have an end. Also the number of line can vary in the file which is why I think i need to loop round until i have the last row then check that has an "END".

I've modified the last code again to include your extra lines, and have modified the run-results for the resultant code. There is no evidence of the extra lines being executed more than once. Works for me.

thanks very much I think the bit I was missing is the knowledge that I can call this bat file from another bat file I can then take the results of this one and take actions on them. Apologies if I was not clear but it's hard to ask the right question when you don't fully understand all of the options. I really feel i have learned a lot from you and appreciate all your help. This is part of a bigger piece of coding I am doing and it is now all coming together.

Here is a quick untested rewrite of your code, which I expect to perform the tasks shown in your own code and within your body text:
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Hard coded for now - this is the value I want to check against.
Set "NewName=SAMPLETEXTTOCHECKN"
Echo File validation and checking for %NewName%
Pause

Set "eMatch="
Set "sMatch="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    'Type "D:\sample.TXT" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N /V ""'
) Do (Set "myVar=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "line="
    For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ("!myVar:*]=!") Do (EndLocal
        Set "line=%%H"
        If Defined line (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ("!line:~,1!") Do (EndLocal
                Set "var="
                For /F "Delims=0123456789" %%J In ("%%I") Do Set "var=%%J"
            )
            If Not Defined var (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%K In ("!line:~46,18!") Do (EndLocal
                    If "%NewName%" == "%%K" (Set "sMatch=T") Else Set "eMatch=T"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
If Defined eMatch (If Not Defined sMatch (
        Echo ERROR: This file does not hold the expected data, please review.
    ) Else Echo ERROR: This file holds multi-client data, please review.
) Else If Defined sMatch Echo SUCCESS: This file holds only the expected data.
If "%myVar:*]=%" == "END" (Echo SUCCESS, valid last line.
) Else Echo ERROR: This file has an invalid last line, please review.
Pause

EndLocal
Exit /B

You should note that it includes the method I initially included in my opening comments.
I will not be providing any help with understanding the code, not will I provide support should anything be changed in the above code, or the originally submitted text file.

@GravyTrain, future readers and I would appreciate it if you could provide feedback on the code and/or results rather than just showing gratitude.

will do i plan to test it tomorrow.

I tested this and the first part works (i.e. the multi client check) but it  incorrectly reports the last line is invalid even when the last row of data is "END". I have tried debugging but unable to see why it is not working. Thanks again for all your help so far, if you are able to help further it would be appreciated but understand if not.

I had time to test this on a customers computer today, @GravyTrain, (I don't have one myself), I recreated your submitted text file, and made copies of it, one with END changed to EOF and one with the numbered lines all matching the first. In all cases the script worked exactly as intended and as posted, (other than the location drive letter D: changed to C:). I am therefore unable to reproduce the issue you are reporting. The only logical reason is that you've changed something, or that you have a line return, (Lf / CrLf), followed by one or more space characters after the END line.

thanks again - I think there must be some spaces after the END entry on my test file. When I pasted these in the original post I think they may have got removed. Are you able to advise how to amend your code to trim the spaces please? I have had a look at how to do this and have found some examples but I don't understand your code well enough to know how to incorporate the changes.

I just checked your initial submission and your first line was \``VOL1FirstLineand your lastEND````, so if they were you removed them yourself. The most important question is, should that actually be a failure?

I had to edit the file to make it generic so that i could post on here. I expect i removed the spaces in error. The last row should read END and if there are spaces these should be ignored. It should pass if there is an END on the final row and fail if there is no END present regardless of spaces.

Would the END check be okay in any position on the last line? (there are no rows in a plain text file), or does it strictly need to be only the first three characters of the last line?
